# Which is the right place to do CRUD action in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a simple API to learn DRF. I've found that it's possible to do crud action in serializers.py or views.py

I read DRF documentation sections below:

[saving instances](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)

[viewset actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions)

Still not quite sure on what option to use.

Comment: It's depend on your demand. There is a view set `ModelViewSet` which djangorestframework created for you to use in some general cases. You can take a look at the source code of the framework to see how they utilize Views, Serializers and Models to create data and save into database.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You can do it either in ***views.py*** or ***serializers.py*** and 
it is suggested that to keep business logic inside ***model manager***.
Happy coding.